# Laravel Nova card action/form

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is it possible to make a card with a action/form inside Laravel Nova?

example:
The card has a file input and a button, when i press the button a script wil run and take the file and do something with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a route for your action and then link or button it on your card.